# Why double quote and <N> cause errors when upload to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Errors were reported when my program tried to upload a `.csv` file, via job upload to BigQuery:

```
Job failed while writing to Bigquery. invalid: Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0. at 
Error: [REASON] invalid [MESSAGE] Data between close double quote (") and field separator: field starts with: <N> [LOCATION] File: 0 / Line:21470 / Field:2
Error: [REASON] invalid [MESSAGE] Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0. [LOCATION]
```

I traced back to my file and did find the specified line like:

```
3D0F92F8-C892-4E6B-9930-6FA254809E58~"N" STYLE TOWING~1~0~5.7.1512.441~10.20.10.25:62342~MSSqlServer: N_STYLE on localhost~3~2015-12-17 01:56:41.720~1~<?xml version="1
```

The delimiter was set to be ~  , then why the double quote or maybe <N> is a problem?

Comment: Check if the syntax to set the delimiter is accurate with a small file, and also check charset.

Comment: Used a more preferred form of formatting errors using code blocks vs. quotes.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Thanks. I also noticed that in quotes, the "<N>" will be taken as an empty character that will not show up in the final post at all. It can show up normally in code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification for csv says that if there is a quote in the field, then the entire field should be quoted. As in `a,b,"c,d"`, which would have only three fields, since the third comma is quoted. The csv parser gets confused when there is data after a closing quote but before the next delimiter, as in `a,b,"c,d"e`.

You can fix this by specifying a custom quote character, since it sounds like you don't need a quote char at all, so you could just set it to something that you'll never see, like `\0` or `|`. You're already setting `configuration.load.delimiter`, just set `configuration.load.quote` as well.

Comment: It solves my problem. Thanks very much. I ended up set configuration.load.quote to an empty string "" which indicates using no quote at all.